# Expressing a series formula

Tags: number-theory

I want to generate a series of the following kind in *Mathematica*:

$\quad \quad a(n+1) = a(n) + ({\rm prime}(n+1) - 1)/2 \quad \mbox{for odd primes},$

so that the resultant series is

> ```
> 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 18, 26, 35, ...
> ```

I have no idea how to find the odd prime numbers.

[Link showing the general formula for series.](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C7%2C12%2C18%2C26%2C35&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Try the function `Prime`.

Comment: please guide about this series also if possible http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80516/series-generation-in-mathematica

Answer (score 5):

Here is a direct implementation of your series formula:

```
a[1] = 1
a[n_] := a[n - 1] + (Prime[n] - 1)/2
```

You can speed up calculation by memoizing `a`:

```
a[1] = 1
a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + (Prime[n] - 1)/2
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the helpful reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `RecurrenceTable`:

```
ClearAll[a, n]
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + (Prime[n + 1] - 1)/2, a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 10}]
(* {1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 18, 26, 35, 46, 60} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Prime[n]` returns the $n$th prime number, and all primes except `Prime[1]` are odd.  So the following works:

```
Accumulate[Prepend[Table[(Prime[i] - 1)/2, {i, 2, 10}], 1]]
```

Comment: thank you. it generated the required results.